# where impelement web3 services : backend or fronend?

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, metamask

I am developing a **social-media-like** application based on ethereum blockchain 
and some use cases are controlled by smart contracts. 
so to communicate with smart contract I have to deal with **web3.**

the question is if I have to implement web3 services at the frontend level **(angular)** because this will need transaction cofirmation and wallet access (exmpl  **metamask)** and keep off-chain business in backend **(nodejs),** or I can impelement all services in **nodejs.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what UX you want to provide. There are generally 3 approaches:

1. **Fully decentralized**: Stand-alone Javascript app which retrieves
   all data from decentralized services, like Ethereum, Swarm and IPFS.
2. **Semi decentralized** approach: Your users have manage their own wallets and use Metamask or other TX signers with javascript based web3 interaction. You May also have a Server Wallet, signing TX server sided.
3. You may manage a Ethereum Wallet for your users, providing them with traditional login. So your whole (**non-decentralized**) blockchain app could be server sided.

In any case you might use node.js as a backend technology or just use it as part of a micro service based Backend architecture.

Just keep in mind, that as soon as you host a wallet for your user, your might turn your server into a hacker honeypot.

Comment: Ok, let's say that I will use metmask to manage wallets. have I implement web3 at the frontend level. and keep other off-chain business in a nodejs server ?

Comment: That sounds right to me. All actions between the user and the blockchain should be initiated by front-end javascript, and completed by the user through metamask.

Comment: You may also check if your favorite backend technology has a well maintained Ethereum implementation. https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js#other-implementations